# How to migrate Borland C++ 5.02 application to Windows 7?

Tags: c++, windows-7, windows-xp, borland-c++

Currently we are migrating our applications developed in Borland C++ 5.02 on Windows XP to Windows 7. While executing the application on Windows 7, I am getting the error message

> VBX library init Failure.

While trying to find the cause on the Internet, I was able to identify the error was because of *BIVBX31N.EXE* and *BIVBX31N.dll*.

How can I port a Borland C++ 5.02 application to Windows 7, solving the *BIVBX31N.EXE* and *BIVBX31N.dll* related issues?

Comment: That toolchain is 15 years old.  You might want to consider a platform switch.  BIVBX31N won't run on 64-bit windows because I believe it has 16-bit code, which is no longer runnable on Win 7 (64 bit at least)

Answer (score 2):

If you're stuck using this product, here is what I recommend.

Simple answer: **Don't use the IDE,** but continue to use the command line tools:

- `bcc32.exe` (the compiler) still works fine in Windows 8.
- `ilink32.exe` (the linker) still works fine as well.

Both can be found in the bin sub-folder.

You can get some of the command line information by opening the IDE (project) file in Notepad or a hex editor (it isn't a text file, but you can read most stuff in Notepad). Or if you do have access to Windows XP you can open it there just to copy the settings for usage in the command-line tools.

Just use some other IDE or editor like [Notepad++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad%2B%2B) to edit your source files. You can use an older version of Visual C++ to edit the RC files, or Notepad or other tools.

If you want really want to make it slick, set up your IDE to run an "external tool" when you click a toolbar button, to have it run your command-line tools to compile + link (and optionally run the EXE file). You can probably find a debugger tool as well, but I haven't needed that yet, so haven't checked.

Answer (score 1):

My best recommendation is to start the process of porting your code to [Visual Studio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio).

You can use a library like [OWLNext](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/owlnext/index.php?title=Main_Page) if you've used the [OWL library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_Windows_Library) in Borland.

The other alternative is is to use [Windows Virtual PC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Virtual_PC) (or other such virtual machine) to run Borland in an integrated Windows XP mode. See an example [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/virtual_pc_guy/archive/2009/06/11/using-windows-virtual-pc-to-run-16-bit-applications-on-64-bit-windows.aspx).

Comment: Porting of c++ code to Visual studio is OK. But how do i handle GUI, events, custom controls, unsupported win16 api's etc. Is there any tool to do this or at-least a tool that takes care of GUI and events

Comment: @vincent If the code you've written is for the win16 API, you'll need to make the necessary changes to that as well.  If the port is too extensive, then a virtual machine would seem the best solution.

Comment: @Jogy I think integrated in Broland.

Comment: @enedil: Borland C++ 5.02 was a command-line compiler, it had no GUI library of its own.  That was introduced in Borland C++Builder using the VCL.  So what are you actually using?

Comment: @RemyLebeau my bad. BTW. I'm not OP.

Comment: @RemyLebeau You may be thinking of BCC++ 5.5 which was only command line tools.
BC5.02 was a full IDE, with a C++ framework - OWL (Object Windows Library)

Answer (score 0):

This can be probable answer ???
You have to download configured Borland Compiler from http://www.4shared.com/get/Gs41_5yA/borland_for_graphics.html or http://dwij.co.in/graphics-c-programming-for-windows-7-borland-compiler/.
Put your Borland’s ‘bin’ folder into Environmental Variables.
Now go inside folder ‘bin’ & edit file bcc32.cfg as per your folder structure. This file contains settings of headers & libraries.

```
-I"D:\Borland\include;"
-L"D:\Borland\lib;D:\Borland\Lib\PSDK"
```

Now create any C/C++ Program say myprogram.cpp
Use following command to compile this bunch of code:

```
F:\>bcc32 myprogram.cpp
```

Congratulations !!!.

Comment: How do you know if you can trust those sites (for instance, not contracting malware)?